# How init value mat-selection-list with FromControl in angular 10

Tags: angular

I can't initialize my component Mat-Selection-Listwith a dynamic value with a FormControl.

The form seems to work but the values in my list are never checked.

```
///ts
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.categoryService.getAllCategory()
  .subscribe(data => {
      this.cbxCategory = data;
    },
    error => console.log(error)
  );
    this.authService.getUser()
      .subscribe(data => {
          this.user = data;
        },
        error => console.log(error),
        
        ()=>this.initForm()
      );
  }

  private initForm() {
    this.editUserForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: new FormControl(this.user.email, [Validators.required,Validators.pattern("^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$"),Validators.maxLength(50)]),
      password: new FormControl(''),
      passwordConfirm: new FormControl(''),
      lstCat: new FormControl(this.user.lstCategory),
    }, {
      validator: MustMatch('password', 'passwordConfirm')
    });
  }
///html
<form [formGroup]="editUserForm" (ngSubmit)="onSave()" >
    <table *ngIf="user">
...
                  <mat-selection-list formControlName="lstCat" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <mat-list-option  *ngFor="let cat of cbxCategory" [value]="cat">
                      {{cat.libelle}}
                    </mat-list-option>
...    
   </table>
  </form>
```

Comment: Can you please create stack blitz to reproduce your issue?

Comment: sorry but no, I need my back

Comment: similar stack https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-etrnoa?file=package.json

Comment: Which version of material are you using in your project?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Angular material 7+ use [compareWith](https://material.angular.io/components/list/api#MatSelectionList) input property on mat-selection-list, which will take function as an input value.

> This Function used for comparing an option against the selected
> value when determining which options should appear as selected

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="clientForm">
  <h1>
    FormControl Value
  </h1>

  <pre>
    {{ clientForm.get('myOtherControl').value | json }}
  </pre>

  <mat-selection-list *ngIf="listValue" formControlName="myOtherControl" [compareWith]="compare" >
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let list of listValue" [value]="list" multiple>{{list.name}}</mat-list-option>
  </mat-selection-list>
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```
 compare(c1: {id: string}, c2: {id: string}) {
    return c1?.id === c2?.id;
  }
```

[Forked Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-questions66654330?file=src/app/list-overview-example.ts)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling initForm method in wrong place.should move initForm method in side the categoryService.getAllCategory() subscribe or if there is dependencies on previous call you could use pipe operator

Comment: i moved "categoryService.getAllCategory() ()=>this.authService.getUser()" but same result. And I added log  line 1 iniform and cbxCategory is not empty.

Comment: If I add a static value also doesn't work